Setting Interpolation Methods for raster layer to bilinear not taking effect
My GeoServer version is 2.25.0. After publishing a single-band raster as a WMS, I configured the layer with a bilinear resampling method. However, when I view the service in the OpenLayer preview, this configuration does not seem to take effect. The backend logs show that the service is actually using the Nearest method. Why is this issue occurring?
The interface for the configuration looks as follows

OpenLayer preview looks as follows，The image still appears as a grid of individual blocks.

The correct bilinear resampling should appear as follows:

The content seen in the logs is as follows:


What format is your raster in? Try turning up the logging level and trying again

I think that I can reproduce with GeoServer 2.25.2 with a demo layer. Logs show CONFIG [coverage.processing] - Apply operation "CoverageCrop" on coverage "usa" with interpolation "Nearest".

@IanTurton The raster format is TIFF, with 8-bit unsigned data, and it is single-band.My logging level is set to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.

@user30184 Is this a bug?

It feels like it is but some GeoServer developer should confirm it.

@user30184 Will a developer verify this issue?
